# Handling corrupt JSON rows in Spark 2.11 - different behaviour than 1.6

Tags: apache-spark

We have snappy files that we read with sql context. e.g.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.json("s3://bucket/problemfile.snappy")
```

In spark 1.6 we would handle corrupt records by something like the below:

```
invalidJSON = rawEvents.select("*").where("_corrupt_record is not null");
validJSON = rawEvents.select("*").where("_corrupt_record is null");
```

In Spark 2.11, we are not even able to read the corrupted record e.g

```
scala> df.select("*").where("_corrupt_record is null").count()

18/03/31 00:45:06 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, ip-172-31-48-73.ec2.internal, executor 2): 
java.io.CharConversionException: Unsupported UCS-4 endianness (3412) detected
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.reportWeirdUCS4(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:469)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.checkUTF32(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:434)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:141)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:215)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createParser(JsonFactory.java:1287)
```

I know we can set spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true in 2.X but that we'd potentially lose records depending on where the corrupted record was.

Is there any other way we can skip over the corrupted record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .json("s3://bucket/problemfile.snappy")
```

This way Spark will drop invalid JSON for you, but you won't see any corrupt record.